# Another question on "Added Cold Damage Support"

Tags: path-of-exile

I have another question on "Added Cold Damage Support". As you can see from the screenshot below: 
[image]
It says that supported skills have 6 to 9 added cold damage. This support gem is linked to Burning Arrow gem: 
[image]
I am having troubles understanding my resulting damage for Burning Arrow:
[image]
Why is main hand cold damage 16-24? What exactly was enhanced by this support gem?
This is what is equipped on me:
[image]
This my skill tree:
[image]
From the skill tree you can see that I have 71% increased projectile damage and 10% increased attack physical damage (does this damage even apply to rangers?)

Comment: Please try to make your question title more specific. Maybe "how is main hand elemental damage calculated", or similar.

Comment: Do you create a new question everytime your cold damage changes in the profile screen? The first answer to your first question already told you how to calculate that, so please read and use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Physical Attack damage applies to all *physical attacks* including bow attacks, however cold is elemental not physical so we ignore the 10% you have for the calculation.

Burning Arrow has 155% effect of added damage. Since added cold damage obviously adds damage we multiply what it gives by 155%:

6-9 * 1.55 = 9.3 - 13.95

You have 71% increased projectile damage. This increases all the damage of your burning arrow (because it is a projectile) which includes the 9-14 damage we got in the last calculation:

9.3-13.95 * 1.71 = **15.9-23.85**.

The game rounds to the nearest whole number so you see 16-24 on your character sheet.

As for your Physical and Fire damage these are the calculations. Starting with the 9-37 physical damage from your bow.

Again Burning Arrows damage effectiveness affects your bows damage:

9-37 * 1.55 = 13.95-57.35

Your passive skill tree has 71% projectile damage and 10% physical attack damage. Since these are both increases they are added together for a total 81% increase:

13.95-57.35 * 1.81 = 25.2-103.8 *physical damage*

Burning arrow converts 50% of this *physical damage* to fire damage:

25.2-103.8 * .5 = 12.6-51.9 rounding to **13-52** for both physical and fire damage.

Comment: Thank you very much, very good explanation. However, from your explanation, it seems that Burning Arrow is supporting the "Added Cold Damage Support" gem by 6-9 * 1.55 = 9.3 - 13.95. I thought that the support is one way, from support gem to supported gem. Am I missing smth? I thought that 155% affects whatever the base damage you have from your weapon, and the support gem will add 6-9 (plus 71%) on top of that.

Comment: Just to clarify i thought that base damage is equal to main hand physical damage, but from your explanation it seems that base damage also includes the cold damage, is this correct?

Comment: Base damage is any whole number damage amount. Added cold damage support has base damage of 6-9. That is added to your bows base damage of 9-37.

Comment: @RustamIssabekov  [Damage effectiveness](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Damage_effectiveness) is present on all skill gems "which serves to limit the potential of base damage added from other sources". So yes, burning arrow is modifying the effects of the support gem in a sense.

Comment: Also while you are here, can you please explain why my "Main hand physical damage" is 13-52 and why my "Main hand fire damage" is 13-52?

Comment: @RustamIssabekov I added it into the answer.

Comment: I just noticed one thing, my bow has 49% increased physical but it seems that its ignored, any ideas?

Comment: @RustamIssabekov weapon mods are typical local modifiers to the weapon itself. If you look at the weapon that is why the physical damage is in blue, to signify it is being changed by mods on the weapon. **A [Long bow](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Long_Bow)'s base damage is 6-25. The 49% physical increases it to 9-37**. That is why the base damage when calculating physical damage for burning arrow was 9-37.